# Remove decimals in price and repleace commas with full stops

Tags: php, html, yii

I am trying to remove decimals from the price showed im my website i have this code

```
<span class="label label-success">
    <?php echo Helper::p($website->price) ?>
</span>
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app() -> getBaseUrl(true) ?>/images/coins.png" alt="<?php echo Yii::t("website", "Coins") ?>">
```

I am getting results like this for example 123.456,78 
I dont want to show the decimals and change the commas to full stops

Example actually i get 123.456,78  but i want to get this format 124,456 as result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
number_format($number, 0, '.', ',')
```

Comment: in your case you have to replace $number by $website->price and awoid use of helper function.

Comment: <span class="label label-success"><?php echo number_format($website->price, 0, '.', ',')?></span>
            <img src="<?php echo Yii::app() -> getBaseUrl(true) ?>/images/coins.png" alt="<?php echo Yii::t("website", "Coins") ?>">